# Rendering calculated columns correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, html

I'm tearing my hair out trying to get a % progress bar based on a calculated column in a list to work. 
I had it working for 24hrs, I tried to guild the lily and it's not worked since. We are on Sharepoint online and there's also a calculation based stoplight column in the same list which is rendering perfectly with a CEWP and the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* Text to HTML - version 2.1.1 */
function TextToHTML(NodeSet, HTMLregexp) {
var CellContent = "";
var i=0;
while (i < NodeSet.length){
try {
CellContent = NodeSet[i].innerText || NodeSet[i].textContent;
if (HTMLregexp.test(CellContent)) {NodeSet[i].innerHTML = CellContent;}
} 
catch(err){}
i=i+1;
}
}

// List views
var regexpTD = new RegExp("^\\s*<([a-zA-Z]*)(.|\\s)*/\\1?>\\s*$");
TextToHTML(document.getElementsByTagName("TD"),regexpTD);
</script>
```

Which i do not really understand but works fine. This has not been changed between the Progress bars working yesterday and them not working today.

The calculation in the column is:

```
="<DIV style='background-color:skyblue;'>
<DIV style='background-color:steelblue;width:"&100-([%Complete]*100)&"%;'>
</DIV>
</DIV>"
```

Which again is a copy and paste from a tutorial with some edits. 
The column output type is set to number.

Where am I going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in SharePoint Online environment, SPO doesn't support calculated columns with markup from June, 2017. You can refer to the [MS documentation here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032106/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields).

Alternatively you can pick CSR/JSLink to make your column render the way you want. You can learn the CSR concept using [this link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a).

**Edit**

1. Create a JS file and put following code in it. Name it `CSR_Demo.js`.

   var FillCtx = {};
   FillCtx.Templates = {};
   FillCtx.Templates.Fields = {'Completed':{'View': fillStatus}}
   function fillStatus(ctx){
       var html ="";
       var fieldVal = ctx.CurrentItem['Completed'];

   ```
   html += "<div class='progress' style='width:400px;'>"+
               "<div class='progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active' role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='" + fieldVal + "' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: " + fieldVal + "%'>"+
                   fieldVal+
               "</div>"+
           "</div>";
   return html;
   ```

   }

   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(FillCtx), 'clienttemplates.js');
2. Upload this file to SiteCollection's `SiteAssets` library under `JS` folder.
3. Now open the List View (or list view web part) where you want to use it.
4. Add the reference to JQuery, Bootstrap CSS and JS. Use `script editor web part` to add script reference on page.
5. Now open the settings of List View Web Part and expand `Miscellaneous`section and in the end find JS link section.
6. Add following URL to JSLink section `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JS/CSR_Demo.js`.

Save your page and you'll see the output like this. Make sure to use proper column name, in my case its `Completed`.

Note: I dont know why it is not formatting code properly, but you have to put the complete within Point 1 and Point 2 in CSR_Demo.js file.

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Oh dear. I have already tried every example on that link and none of them work for me.

Comment: can you share the code you tried? We can see whats going wrong in your case

Comment: The code currently in use is above. The code I used in the examples on the link given I copied verbatim. My guess its it's not finding the file but when I try to use jslink it tends to result in a completely blank page and I have to reserect the page with SPD and version history.

Comment: edited the code for you.

Comment: thank you. Could you clarify point 4 please? "Add the reference to JQuery, Bootstrap CSS and JS" I'm a coding beginner so this is greek to me...

Comment: also the 2nd point? what script goes in the script web part if the JS code goes in the seperate file?

Comment: put all the scripts in script editor web part. The first reference must be of Bootstrap css, next must be JQuery, next Bootstrap JavaScript and finally your `<script>` block containing the script i provided.

Comment: JQuery is JS based framework while Bootstrap is responsive framework. Jquery CDN url https://code.jquery.com/ and Bootstrap CDN url http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Use w3school to learn these two framework...wont take much time. Following is the URL. https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: OK thats so far beyond me. Think we'll have to do without the progress bars now. thanks for trying. :-)